# Custom operator support in naming convention

Tags: spring-data-jpa

as we know, spring-data-jpa supports repositories that generate queries based on function names, i.e (kotlin):

```
@Repository
interface LocationRepository : JpaRepository<DbLocation, UUID>, 
JpaSpecificationExecutor<DbLocation>{
    fun findOneByNameIgnoringCase(name: String)
}
```

Now, postgres supports some custom operators, for example timerange '@>' timestamp (read: timerange contains timestamp).

I'd like to have a function like this, without resorting to native queries/specifications:

```
@Repository
interface LocationRepository : JpaRepository<DbLocation, UUID>, 
JpaSpecificationExecutor<DbLocation>{
    fun findOneBySomeFieldContainsTimestamp(something: Instant)
}
```

Is there any way to extend spring data jpa to also support new operators?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to extend Spring Data JPA to also support new operators?

Not really.

Of course, technically the answer is *yes* since Spring Data is Open Source and you can fork it. A good starting point would be [`JpaQueryCreator.build()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/70d1012ac3ae12f7c7ad4060318ac61a8059db19/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryCreator.java#L240) which contains a switch statement for all the supported operators.